# Usage of HashSet.contains()

Tags: java, set

I have a class with 3 attributes. One of the attributes is used as a unique key , so I use that one key in my `equals` and `hashcode` method.

Now once the set is built, during lookup, I have only the primary key (unique key) and I will have to construct a dummy object with unique key and setting other two values to 0 (default values) and then I say

```
Chapter myObject = new Chapter(uniqueKey,0,0);
hashSet.contains(myObject); // This will work.
```

Is this a correct usage for Hashset lookup? Is there any other better way because I am not a fan of setting bogus values on a object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to make this less verbose is to define a `Chapter()` constructor that takes a `uniqueKey` argument and fills in the rest, and then use:

```
hashSet.contains(new Chapter(uniqueKey));
```

Since you are throwing away the object anyways.

However, since you have a `uniqueKey`, which I assume is unique to each instance of a `Chapter`, have you considered using a `HashMap` instead? Then you could just use `uniqueKey` as keys, and you'd just have to check whether the key is present (eg: using [`HashMap.containsKey()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)) or not:

```
hashMap.containsKey(uniqueKey);
```

With a HashMap, you can also just get the Object you want with `.get()`:

```
Chapter c = hashMap.get(uniqueKey);
```

This will give you the `Chapter` object if the supplied `uniqueKey` maps to an object, or `null` if doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Typically in this situation you should consider refactoring your key fields into a separate key class and then using a `HashMap` rather than a `HashSet`.  This avoids the need to create an entire dummy object; all that is required is that you create an instance of the key.

**Example**

```
public class Foo {
  public static class Key {
    private final String s;
    private final int i;

    public Key(String s, int i) {
      this.s = s;
      this.i = i;
    }

    // TODO: Implement equals / hashCode.
  }

  private final Key key;
  private final double d;

  public class Foo(String s, int i, double d) {
    this(new Key(s, i), d);
  }

  public class Foo(Key key, double d) {
    this.key = key;
    this.d = d;
  }

  public Key getKey() { return key; }      

  // TODO: Implement equals / hashCode to delegate to Key.
}
```

Objects are then created and added to the map as follows:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo("Hello", 5, 10.0);
Foo foo2 = new Foo("Goodbye", 10, 20.0);

Map<Foo.Key, Foo> foosByKey = new HashMap<Foo.Key, Foo>();

foosByKey.put(foo1.getKey(), foo1);
foosByKey.put(foo2.getKey(), foo2);
```

... and the map can be queried by simply creating a Key instance:

```
if (foosByKey.contains(new Foo.Key("Hello", 5))) {
  System.err.println("BOOM!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want lookup, you may be better off going with a HashMap instead of a HashSet.  Then you can use your primary key as the key in the map, and the object as the value, then you can do

```
MyObject o = map.get(myKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

You approach seems a little round-about. Why not just keep a set of keys? Or, if you need access to the object via the key, then you should use a `HashMap`, rather than a `HashSet`.